# XCode 6.3 cannot show navigation bar

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I am not doing something complicated here. I have a UITableView created using storyboards. Just shows some data and has a navigation bar in order to place a title and an action button. However the bar is not showing when I am running my app. Xcode is 6.3. Any clue? Usually this works without adding a line of code.

I did a fresh build, however the problem is still there.

The view is loaded like this

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"RecentCalls" bundle:nil];                    
MyController *r = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RecentCallsBoard"];
[viewControllers addObject:r]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use the Debug->View Debugging menu to take a snapshot of the UI and look at which views are on screen, their positions, and whether there are occlusions.

Comment: I did it, but I cannot see the navigation bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make sure that the checkbox at "Shows Navigation Bar" in your Attributes Inspector is ticked?

[image]

**Edit**

I see that you're using this line:

```
[viewControllers addObject:r]
```

Why are you doing this? Your UINavigationController should be configured as "Initial View Controller". You've already setup the segue to your UITableViewController, so that should work.

**Edit 2**

I think this causes the problem:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"RecentCalls" bundle:nil];
```

You shouldn't instantiate your "RecentCalls" view controller, but your Root Navigation Controller instead. Otherwise it navigates directly to your UITableViewController, what causes the absence of the UINavigationBar.

Comment: Yes, this options is enabled.

Comment: The storyboard is loaded from a tab bar. Every tab item has a storyboard, therefore I need to add this to the viewControllers object.

Comment: thanks very much. I have already placed the name storyboardid before embeding the tableview to the navigation controller.